# Can an async method await multiple responses?

Tags: c#, async-await, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am learning more about Mass Transit in my free time.  Please see the code below:

```
var serviceAddress = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/check-order-status");
var client = bus.CreateRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus>(serviceAddress);
var response = await client.GetResponse<OrderStatusResult>(new { OrderId = id});
```

which I took from here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html

GetResponse sends a message to a rabbitmq fan out exchange, which has x consumers.  Each consumer needs to send a reply to the publisher, however the code above will only receive one reply and then carry on.  How can it receive x replies?

I have managed to do this with RabbitMQ (without Mass Transit) like this: https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/05/12/messaging-with-rabbitmq-and-net-c-part-5-headers-and-scattergather/.  However, I cannot work out how to do it with mass transit.

Can an async method await multiple replies?

**Update**

Using a handler appears to work:

```
 sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, myMessage.Id.ToString(), ep =>
                {
                    ep.Handler<MyMessage>(context =>
                    {
                        testlist.Add(context.Message);
                        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Name}");
                    });
                });
```

I can now access testlist inside the sender.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to achieve similar behaviour than the scatter/gather example by using [Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8). There is a section in the Mass Transit request-response page on how to use it on [Composing multiple results](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html#composing-multiple-requests).

Following the example code from Mass Transit, suppose that you have multiple serviceAddresses stored in a field:

```
ICollection<Uri> _serviceAddresses;
```

If you want to get CheckOrderStatus responses from all the clients, you can do it as follows:

```
var getResponseTasks = new List<Task<Response<CheckOrderStatus>>>();
foreach(var serviceAdress in _serviceAddresses)
{
    var client = bus.CreateRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus>(serviceAddress);
    getResponseTasks.Add(client.GetResponse<OrderStatusResult>(new { OrderId = id}));
}

await Task.WhenAll(getResponseTasks);
```

Now you'll just have to unwrap the results:

```
var responses = new List<Response<CheckOrderStatus>>();
foreach(var responseTask in getResponseTasks)
{
    var response = await responseTask;
    responses.Add(response);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean the publisher has to know who all the consumers are? The whole point of decoupled distributed systems avoids this.  If I use rabbitmq alone (without mass transit), then the publisher does not know who the x (x is a number) consumers are.  If I use mass transit then it appears I have to hardcode the consumers inside the publisher (as you have done).  Have i understood this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 your comment is not clear, how is what he showed you any different from what you are doing

Comment: @johnny 5, the point I am making is that the sender has to know who all of the receivers are.  If I was using RabbitMQ alone then the sender does not need to know who the receivers are as shown in the second link of my question.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Does the sender have to know all of the receivers when implementing scatter/gather using mass transit?

Comment: @w0051977 Looks like I might have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. Am I correct that you are not trying to collect data from multiple 'RequestClients', but you want to handle several responses from a single service?

Comment: I am trying to collect data from multiple request clients.  I have added an update to my question.  Does it make sense?